# How to make ranking system in java

Tags: java

I have custom object for example person. Every person have a rank, social number and points. Whats the most efficient way to order the persons by points and rank them. What I should use - Comparator, Map or override the add method of some list ? How it can be made in most efficient way?

Comment: well... some code would have been useful.. but usually  a comaprator/comparable are used for sorting

Comment: Welcome to SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may be a [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/).

Comment: Please give more information we cant help you then you say." i have no idea what i am doing pls help"

Comment: @JasonC - lol.. seems like one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Oracle: Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

```
package main;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private final String rank;
    private final int points;

    public Person(String rank, int points) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String rank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int points() {
        return points;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Person))
            return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return person.rank.equals(rank) && person.points == points;
    }

    // public int hashCode() {
    //    return your hash;
    // }

    public String toString(){
        return "Rank: " + rank +", points = " + points ;
    }
    
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        return points > person.points ? 1 : points < person.points ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Then test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Person usersArray[] = { new Person("RankX", 1), new Person("RankY", 100),
   new Person("RankZ", 44), new Person("RankF", 21) };

   List<Person> users = Arrays.asList(usersArray);
   Collections.sort(users);
   System.out.println(users);
        
   Collections.sort(users, Collections.reverseOrder());
   System.out.println(users);
}
```

Output

> [Rank: RankX, points = 1, Rank: RankF, points = 21, Rank: RankZ, points =
> 44, Rank: RankY, points = 100]
>
> [Rank: RankY, points = 100, Rank: RankZ,
> points = 44, Rank: RankF, points = 21, Rank: RankX, points = 1]